# A windowed operation on a pandas data frame to list Euclidean distance from the previous n entries

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, euclidean-distance, rolling-computation

I have a sorted (on 'values') dataframe that looks like the following. The unnamed col us the index.

```
        x_cord  y_cord  value
3384209 1650    1741    0.009752
3382265 1650    1740    0.009481
3384208 1649    1741    0.008943
3382264 1649    1740    0.008676
3384210 1651    1741    0.008473
... ... ... ...
1679661 46      865     0.000000
1679660 45      865     0.000000
1679659 44      865     0.000000
1679658 43      865     0.000000
5038847 1944    2592    0.000000
```

How can I create another col with a list of euclidean distances to the previous n rows? For example the

- first row will have an empty list
- second row will have a list of distance between the first and second row (see co-ords) i.e. 1 item.
- third row will have. list of two items i.e. between third and second
  as well as third and first.
- the 21st row will have a list of ten items with euclidean distances between itself and the previous nine points.

The list will always ever have a max of ten (or n) elements.

How can I achieve this?

FYI

```
def euc_distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy to the rescue! (A *fast* solution, mostly vectorized):

```py
def fun(k, z):
    na = np.full((k, z.shape[1]), np.nan)
    a = np.row_stack((na, z[:-k, :]))
    return np.linalg.norm(z - a, axis=1)

vfun = np.vectorize(fun, signature='(),(n,m)->(n)')
```

Now, you can get an array `(n, k)` with all the distances:

```py
>>> k = 4  # just for nice printing; replace with 10 in your setting
>>> z = pd.DataFrame(vfun(range(1, k+1), df[['x_cord', 'y_cord']].values).T)
... z
             0            1            2            3
0          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN
1     1.000000          NaN          NaN          NaN
2     1.414214     1.000000          NaN          NaN
3     1.000000     1.000000     1.414214          NaN
4     2.236068     2.000000     1.414214     1.000000
5  1828.496924  1826.262303  1826.741635  1827.140115
6     1.000000  1829.374757  1827.140115  1827.619216
7     1.000000     2.000000  1830.252715  1828.018052
8     1.000000     2.000000     3.000000  1831.130798
9  2568.332144  2567.592063  2566.852158  2566.112429
```

You may transform that into lists if you prefer:

```py
>>> z.apply(list, axis=1)
0                                 [nan, nan, nan, nan]
1                                 [1.0, nan, nan, nan]
2                  [1.4142135623730951, 1.0, nan, nan]
3                  [1.0, 1.0, 1.4142135623730951, nan]
4     [2.23606797749979, 2.0, 1.4142135623730951, 1.0]
5    [1828.4969237053695, 1826.2623031755325, 1826....
6    [1.0, 1829.3747565766835, 1827.1401150431786, ...
7    [1.0, 2.0, 1830.2527147910475, 1828.018052427273]
8                  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1831.1307981681703]
9    [2568.3321436294023, 2567.592062614309, 2566.8...
```

Putting it all together:

```py
out = df.assign(
    distances=pd.DataFrame(
        vfun(list(range(1, k+1)), df[['x_cord', 'y_cord']].values).T,
        index=df.index,
    ).apply(list, axis=1)
)
```

Out:

```
         x_cord  y_cord     value  \
3384209    1650    1741  0.009752   
3382265    1650    1740  0.009481   
3384208    1649    1741  0.008943   
3382264    1649    1740  0.008676   
3384210    1651    1741  0.008473   
1679661      46     865  0.000000   
1679660      45     865  0.000000   
1679659      44     865  0.000000   
1679658      43     865  0.000000   
5038847    1944    2592  0.000000   

                                                 distances  
3384209                               [nan, nan, nan, nan]  
3382265                               [1.0, nan, nan, nan]  
3384208                [1.4142135623730951, 1.0, nan, nan]  
3382264                [1.0, 1.0, 1.4142135623730951, nan]  
3384210   [2.23606797749979, 2.0, 1.4142135623730951, 1.0]  
1679661  [1828.4969237053695, 1826.2623031755325, 1826....  
1679660  [1.0, 1829.3747565766835, 1827.1401150431786, ...  
1679659  [1.0, 2.0, 1830.2527147910475, 1828.018052427273]  
1679658                [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1831.1307981681703]  
5038847  [2568.3321436294023, 2567.592062614309, 2566.8...
```

For your case, set `k=10` instead of 4.

Answer (score 0):

First, shift all the 10 previous rows, in a dedicated column for each shift:

```
for i in range(1,11):
    df["x_cord_"+str(i)] = df["x_cord"].shift(i)
    df["y_cord_"+str(i)] = df["y_cord"].shift(i)
```

Then, compute the distance between each row and the 10 other coordinates now stored in their dedicated columns. The `if` ensures that if there is a `Nan` in the column, the resulting list will not contain this value.

```
df["distance"] = df.apply(lambda row: [euc_distance(row["x_cord"], row["y_cord"], row["x_cord_"+str(i)], row["y_cord_"+str(i)]) for i in range(1,11)  if not math.isnan(row["x_cord_"+str(i)])], axis=1)
```

To finish, delete the columns only created for the calculation.

```
df = df[["x_cord", "y_cord", "value", "distance"]]
```

Output:

```
          x_cord  y_cord       value    distance
3384209     1650    1741    0.009752    []
3382265     1650    1740    0.009481    [1.0]
3384208     1649    1741    0.008943    [1.4142135623730951, 1.0]
3382264     1649    1740    0.008676    [1.0, 1.0, 1.4142135623730951]
3384210     1651    1741    0.008473    [2.23606797749979, 2.0, 1.4142135623730951, 1.0]
```

It may be improvable.